Power supply A output
I need to replace the power supply for a printer as the one it came with fails during high density prints. The input on it is 110 – 240V ~ 1A 50 / 60Hz and the output is 24V ⎓ 2A. After looking at the manual for the printer, I found out that I need a power supply that can provide peak currents of at least 3.2 A. I have found a potential replacement with an input of 110 – 240V ~ 1.5A 50 / 60Hz and an output of 24V ⎓ 6A 144W. Would the excess output cause any damage to the printer or would the printer only pull as much as it needs?

Match the voltage, the current of the supply needs to be more than the device

The displayed current is the maximum current the power supply CAN provide. The printer will only use as much as it needs.
